# filetype and vim syntax highlighting for the output of ipython

Tags: vim, ipython, syntax-highlighting

In `ipython`, I can use `?` to get the doc for the object preceding it, like `os.path.join?<enter>`. Then I get the output like this:

```
Signature: os.path.join(a, *p)
Docstring:
Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.
If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
will be discarded.  An empty last part will result in a path that
ends with a separator.
File:      ~/conda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py
Type:      function
```

I want to load this output into Vim and get the syntax highlighting.

1. Which `filetype` should I set for it?
2. If no existing `filetype` describes this format, how to set the syntax highlight for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Vim came with a syntax highlighting for it, there would most likely also be a *filetype detection* for it, as these usually come together. You could search the Internet whether someone has already created a syntax for that and published it, on [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/) and/or in a GitHub repository.

To start developing your own syntax see [`:help :syn-define`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-define) and [`:help usr_44.txt`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_44.txt.html#usr_44.txt).

For example, to highlight the `Signature:`, `File:`, ... prefixes, you'd use:

```
syntax match pythondocPrefix "^\a\+:"
```

Instead of defining custom colors, it is recommended to link to existing highlight groups; cp. [`:help highlight-groups`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#highlight-groups).

```
highlight def link pythondocPrefix Type
```

This is just a start; you can define as many distinct elements as you like! It helps to look at existing syntax scripts (in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/`) to see how it's done. For the Python string after `Signature:`, it would be nice to include the Python syntax there; see [`:help :syn-include`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-include).

You'd put all these commands into a file `~/.vim/syntax/pythondoc.vim`. [`:help 44.12`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_44.txt.html#44.12) has additional tips.

Usually, you'd then define a [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype) with detection, but as you apparently want to trigger the doc lookup via a custom mapping or command, you can just directly `:setlocal syntax=pythondoc` in that scratch buffer.

Comment: Perhaps somebody already created this *filetype* (not possibly with python in its name). But where to look for the available filetypes and should should I look for? May be there is already a more general filetype that handles this `key: description` format

Comment: Well, `:setf <C-d>` gives you the list of all filetypes you have. You can "try out" some promising names and check how its syntax looks.

Comment: en, didn't found an existing one that describes this. need to take sometime to implement a new. Thanks